# How to redirect all traffic via .htaccess to https

Tags: .htaccess, https, subdomain

I have wasted endless hours trying to redirect all traffic (domain.com,www.domain.com, chat.domain.com) to https. I want to keep the domain name generic because there are other domain names parked on the site.

The best rules I could come up with so far, after lots of googling, trial and error, is this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Unfortunately, these rules do NOT work for URLs belong to the subdomain.

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working for subdomains? From what I see this rule is correct.

Comment: Do you have a valid SSL certificate for the subdomains?

Answer (score 0):

Go through the following checklist:

1. The SSL certificate is valid.
2. The rule is defined somewhere all subdomains can actually visit 9and will have to visit).
3. If the rules are inside an `htaccess` file, the `AllowOverride` directive is set to `All` in server configuration.